# keras imbalance data training weight adjustment

Tags: python, keras, neural-network, imbalanced-data

I am interested in training a regression model to predict price(numerous value) I have two data sources. One comes from 2019 and another year is 2020. 2019 has over 3times more data than 2020. I know I can do oversample to adjust this imbalance data.

However is there a way to adjust the training weights in a fully connected neutral network? Like class_weight or sample_weight?

Btw, the year(2019 and 2020)is not a feature gonna be used in the model.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm just curious. Why would adjust the weight will help with imbalance data? Sure, it is possible to adjust the weight and bias of parameter manually, but that is the duty of gradient optimization isn't it.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/31129/sample-importance-training-weights-in-keras. They explained in detail what you are looking for.

Anyway, why would you adjust the weights if the year information is useless? If it is in fact useless, there is no need to care about it.

Answer (score 0):

TensorFlow also wrote a guide about how to handle imbalance data, you can read it [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/structured_data/imbalanced_data)